# use a var in [RUN] section

Tags: inno-setup

i wish to read a var value in [RUN] section, kets say this is my code -

```
[Setup]

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Description: ""; parameters:"/setid=SessionIDValue"

[code]
var

    SessionIDValue: String;

procedure InitializeWizard();

  begin

    SessionIDValue:= 'test';

    end;
```

Is it possible to pass `SessionIDValue` value to `parameters:"/setid=SessionIDValue"`

10X FOR THE HELP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a scripted [`{code:...}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) constant getter function to bridge the [`[Code]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcreating) section with scripting sections, e.g.:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Parameters: "{code:GetSessionID}"

[Code]
var
  SessionID: string;

function GetSessionID(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := SessionID;
end;
```

Comment: 10x again, Tlama
I know this solution,isn't there a much simpler way to pass the pass the var value?
inno setup cant pass var in it's sections?

Comment: No, there isn't. Inno Setup doesn't have an expandable constant (like e.g. `{reg:}`, `{param:}` etc.) for global variables declared in `[Code]` section. This is the only way at this time.

Comment: It's worth to mention that you can write one getter for many variables and return variable values depending on the input parameter, e.g. by index like [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/fehb0vDe).